# Ipad App SplitView the master view disappears

Tags: ios, ipad, splitview

i've created the user interface for an ipad app. I used the splitview to do the layout. However, When I run the app, the master view doesn't show up in the simulator. (The app is now only supported in landscape view.) Does anyone have idea of what problem it can be? Many thanks!!

Comment: Can you please post your sample code. Without knowing how you are setting up the splitview, it will be difficult to dissect the problem.

Comment: Hi I've sorted it out! It's something about table view controller. Thanks anyway! Can you please look a bit at my new question as well? The linker error? :D